# getSOAPBody returns NULL whereas SOAPResponse.writeTo prints the whole message, Strange?

Tags: java, soap

I am providing a java code which i found on here somewhere on stack overflow and i want to use something similar for my purpose. This code works alright but there is a persistent issue that i face. Check the sys outs i have done in the code. The first 2 sys outs that i print to get the SOAP body of the response return me a null whereas when i try to print the whole response it prints accurately. Its very strange.

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it. I am using JDK 1.7

```
package trials;

import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;


public class SOAPClientSAAJ {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    // Create SOAP Connection
    SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

    // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
    String url = "http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx";
    SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

    System.out.println("Body");

    // print SOAP Response
    System.out.print("Response SOAP Message:");

   System.out.println("SOAP Body 2= " + soapResponse.getSOAPBody());

   System.out.println("SOAP Body 2=" + soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getBody());

    soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);


    soapConnection.close();
}

private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    String serverURI = "http://ws.cdyne.com/";

    // SOAP Envelope
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("example", serverURI);

    /*
    Constructed SOAP Request Message:
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:example="http://ws.cdyne.com/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <example:VerifyEmail>
                <example:email>mutantninja@gmail.com</example:email>
                <example:LicenseKey>123</example:LicenseKey>
            </example:VerifyEmail>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
     */

    // SOAP Body
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("VerifyEmail", "example");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("email", "example");
    soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("mutantninja@gmail.com");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("LicenseKey", "example");
    soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("123");

    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI  + "VerifyEmail");

    soapMessage.saveChanges();


    /* Print the request message */
    System.out.print("Request SOAP Message:");
    soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);        
    System.out.println();




    return soapMessage;
}
```

}

This is the output that i get on console

```
Request SOAP Message:<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP- ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:example="http://ws.cdyne.com/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><example:VerifyEmail><example:email>mutantninja@gmail.com</example:email><example:LicenseKey>123</example:LicenseKey></example:VerifyEmail></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
Body
Response SOAP Message:SOAP Body 2= [soap:Body: null]
SOAP Body 2=[soap:Body: null]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soap:Body><VerifyEmailResponse xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/"><VerifyEmailResult><ResponseText>Mail Server will accept email</ResponseText><ResponseCode>3</ResponseCode><LastMailServer>gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com</LastMailServer><GoodEmail>true</GoodEmail></VerifyEmailResult></VerifyEmailResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 3):

`toString()` for `Node` is implemented as `["+getNodeName()+": "+getNodeValue()+"]`, and `getNodeValue()` will be null for element nodes. Therefore, you'll get `[soap:Body: null]`.

However, the body is there, and you can work with it as you normally would.

Try the following to see that all of the elements are there:

```
SOAPBody body = soapResponse.getSOAPBody();
System.out.println(body.getElementsByTagName("ResponseText").item(0).getTextContent());
System.out.println(body.getElementsByTagName("ResponseCode").item(0).getTextContent());
System.out.println(body.getElementsByTagName("GoodEmail").item(0).getTextContent());
```

Comment: Thanks. but then i was trying to unmarshall it to a java class to get the SOAP body as a java object. That didn't work because of this NULL issue i guess. Any pointers ?

Comment: It's unlikely that `null` is the cause, because the body is present. Perhaps you should create a new question with your unmarshalling code and a description of the problem.

Comment: here is my new post with the unmarshal code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719586/cannot-unmarshal-soap-body-to-java-object

Answer (score 2):

i followed the same tutorial as you did.

and faced the same problem, just if anybody else need this , i solved the problem by deleting the name space alias "example", in the inner nodes, I only left it in the first parameter node `search`:

```
 SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("search", "example");  /*"example"*/

SOAPElement soapBodyElem0 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("arg0");
SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem0.addChildElement("name");
soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("test");
SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem0.addChildElement("number");
soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("5");

MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI  + "search");
```

as i saw in the SoapUI autogenerated XML (only in `search` node)

```
 <example:search>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <name>234</name>
            <number>5</number>
         </arg0>
      </example:search>
```

This solved my problem.