# Cannot unmarshal soap body to java object

Tags: soap

This is related to my earlier post here [getSOAPBody returns NULL whereas SOAPResponse.writeTo prints the whole message, Strange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26709562/getsoapbody-returns-null-whereas-soapresponse-writeto-prints-the-whole-message)

I am posting my code that i am using to unmarshal. I receive all nulls in the target object

```
package trials;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class SOAPClientSAAJ {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // Create SOAP Connection
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
        String url = "http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx";
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

        System.out.println("Body");

        // print SOAP Response
        System.out.print("Response SOAP Message:");

        System.out.println("SOAP Body 2= " + soapResponse.getSOAPBody());

        System.out.println("SOAP Body 2=" + soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getBody());

        soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);
        SOAPBody body = soapResponse.getSOAPBody();
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println(body.getElementsByTagName("ResponseText").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println(body.getElementsByTagName("ResponseCode").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println(body.getElementsByTagName("GoodEmail").item(0).getTextContent());

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        soapResponse.writeTo(bos);
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        StreamSource xml = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()));
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);
        xsr.nextTag();
        while (!xsr.getLocalName().equals("VerifyEmailResult")) {
            xsr.nextTag();
        }

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(VerifyEmailResult.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<VerifyEmailResult> jb = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, VerifyEmailResult.class);
        xsr.close();

        VerifyEmailResult v = jb.getValue();
        System.out.println(v.ResponseText);
        System.out.println(v.ResponseCode);
        System.out.println(v.LastMailServer);
        System.out.println(v.GoodEmail);

        soapConnection.close();
    }



private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    String serverURI = "http://ws.cdyne.com/";

    // SOAP Envelope
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("example", serverURI);

    /*
     * Constructed SOAP Request Message: <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
     * xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     * xmlns:example="http://ws.cdyne.com/"> <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
     * <SOAP-ENV:Body> <example:VerifyEmail>
     * <example:email>mutantninja@gmail.com</example:email>
     * <example:LicenseKey>123</example:LicenseKey> </example:VerifyEmail>
     * </SOAP-ENV:Body> </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
     */

    // SOAP Body
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("VerifyEmail", "example");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("email", "example");
    soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("mutantninja@gmail.com");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("LicenseKey", "example");
    soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("123");

    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI + "VerifyEmail");

    soapMessage.saveChanges();

    /* Print the request message */
    System.out.print("Request SOAP Message:");
    soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
    System.out.println();

    return soapMessage;
}
```

}

Here is my class which i am trying to unmarshal to

```
package trials;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public  class VerifyEmailResult {
    public String ResponseText;
    public String ResponseCode;
    public String LastMailServer;
    public String GoodEmail;
}
```

Here is my console output

```
Request SOAP Message:<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:example="http://ws.cdyne.com/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><example:VerifyEmail><example:email>mutantninja@gmail.com</example:email><example:LicenseKey>123</example:LicenseKey></example:VerifyEmail></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
Body
Response SOAP Message:SOAP Body 2= [soap:Body: null]
SOAP Body 2=[soap:Body: null]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soap:Body><VerifyEmailResponse xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/"><VerifyEmailResult><ResponseText>Current license key only allows so many checks</ResponseText><ResponseCode>9</ResponseCode><LastMailServer/><GoodEmail>false</GoodEmail></VerifyEmailResult></VerifyEmailResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

Current license key only allows so many checks
9
false
null
null
null
null
```

Comment: wow ! whats your JDK version and whats the OS

Comment: JDK8. I don't think the OS has anything to do with it, but it's Windows 8.

Comment: ah ! so now i am stuck. any pointers on how to proceed. I am using a Mac and JDK7

Comment: You can try JDK8, or the latest JDK7 release and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
response.response.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument()
```

I was facing the same problem and it is fixed with below code :

```
        SOAPMessage response = dispatch.invoke(request);
        Document document = response.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument();
        NodeList list = document.getChildNodes();
        System.out.println("Value : " + list.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent());
```

Hope this helps